# Is this the right place to ask hypothetical terraforming questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to know whats a proper venue for questions about hypothetical terraforming scenarios. Ex: "What if terraformed using fusion ... "

This seemed like a good place but a question I posted immediately got a down vote so I deleted it and am now wondering where to take such questions.

Comment: worldbuilding might be a better fit, although it depends on the exact details of your question.

Answer (score 5):

Some might be on topic here. If it is more rooted in the short term then this might be a fine site, but otherwise I would try http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com .